# Bazel cannot find maven dependency

Tags: maven, bazel

I receive the following error when I build a simple toy project using bazel:

```
$ bazel build :example-test
ERROR: /home/ubuntu/foo/scala_bazel_test/src/scala/test/src/com/foo/util/BUILD:1:1: no such package '@org_scalatest//jar': Failed to fetch Maven dependency: Could not find artifact org.scalatest:scalatest_2_11:jar:3.0.1 in org_scalatest (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) and referenced by '//src/scala/test/src/com/foo/util:example-test'
```

The relevant portion of the BUILD and WORKSPACE files are the following:
BUILD:

```
scala_test(
  name = "example-test",
  srcs = glob(["**/*.scala"]),
  deps = [
    "@org_scalatest//jar",
    "@junit//jar",
    "@org_hamcrest//jar",
    "//src/scala/main/src/com/foo/util:example-lib"]
)
```

WORKSPACE:

```
...
maven_jar(
  name = "org_scalatest",
  artifact = "org.scalatest:scalatest_2_11:3.0.1",
)
```

The error suggests I have given either the wrong name or wrong artifact for downloading this dependency, but it's not clear what the issue is. I can access the requested version of scalatest in my browser at:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.11/3.0.1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, an underscore instead of a period in the artifact name.